# Program to Unjumble Words on Python

Tags: python

I want to write a program in python that will unjumble a given string of letters. I also want this program to only give me words whose length is equal to the entered jumbled string. For example if input id "dgo" "dog" and "god" are viable answers but not "go". 
Any ideas or suggestions on how i will go about writing this program?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many ways to do this. This simplest would just be to find every permutation of letters of the word, then compare the permutations against a dictionary. As it stands though, this question is too broad.

Comment: I had thought to do that but i didnt know how to permute the entered word or check it against the word. How should i go about doing that.

Comment: That question gets asked here several times a day. Just search "python permutation".

Comment: Consider the input "dgo", if you make it a list("dgo") you have ["d","g","o"] - go from there...

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Do *not* calculate permutation. It's extremely inefficient and not required. Simply sort the letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need a database of viable words. An english dictionary will do.

One way is to check for words in the database that are **anagrams** of the jumbled string. Here's a naive algo:

read the viable words into an appropriate data structure a python `dict` or `tuple` will suffice. Assume the viable words are stored in a list: `wordlist`

sort the jumbled word and compare it to each of the (sorted) words in wordlist in turn.

Print each positive result.

A simple implementation will look like this:

```
sorted_jumbled_word = "".join(sorted(jumbled_word))
for word in wordlist:
    if sorted_jumbled_word == "".join(sorted(word)):
        print(word)
```

Note this is extremely inefficient (as it will search the entire list of viable words). You can use a dictionary of containing sorted words as keys and every possible anagram as the values.
However this should get you started.

Comment: Sorting is the correct way, in order to avoid to calculate permutations. Using a `defaultdict(list)` (e.g. `"dgo" : ['dog', 'god']`) would be indeed the most efficient way.

Comment: @EricDuminil I agree with you. If the op is just starting to learn python and (this problem) it is best to grasp this simple solution before moving on to other more advanced techniques.